# fetching content from a webpage using curl

Tags: php, curl, html, fetch

First of all have a look at here,

```
www.zedge.net/txts/4519/
```

this page has so many text messages , I want my script to open each of the message and download it,
but i am having some problem,

This is my simple script to open the page,

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.zedge.net/txts/4519");
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

The page download fine but how would i open every text message page inside this page one by one and save its content in a text file,
I know how to save the content of a webpage in a text file using curl but in this case there are so many different pages inside the page i've downloaded how to open them one by one seperately ?

I've this idea but don't know if it will work,

Downlaod this page,

```
www.zedge.net/txts/4519
```

look for the all the links of text messages page inside the page and save each link into one text file (one in each line), then run another curl session , open the text file read each link one by one , open it copy the content from the particular DIV and then save it in a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty straight forward:

- download `www.zedge.net/txts/4519` with curl
- parse it with [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (or alternative) for links
- either store them all into text file/database or process them on the fly with "subrequest"

```
// Load main page
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.zedge.net/txts/4519");
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $contents);

// Filter all the links
$xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom);
$items = $xPath->query( '//a[class=myLink]');

foreach( $items as $link){
    $url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if( strncmp( $url, 'http', 4) != 0){
        // Prepend http:// or something
    }

    // Open sub request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.zedge.net/txts/4519");
    $subContent = curl_exec( $ch);
}
```

See documentation and examples for [`xPath::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php), note that [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) implements `Traversable` and therefor you can use `foreach`.

Tips:

- Use curl opt `COOKIE_JAR_FILE`
- Use `sleep(...)` not to flood server
- Set php time and memory limit

Comment: i don't know much about DOM , when i open the link you've provided for DOM there are infinite things to read :O , btw i tried your code it shows an error 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Empty string supplied as input in E:\Installations\xampp\htdocs\wp\test1.php on line 7

Comment: @Xufyan check content of `$contents` (`var_dump($contents)`)

Comment: I didn't get you , searched alot :/ could you please explain

Comment: At first you have to have correct `$contents` so you have to check whether `$contents` is empty or not... (curl request was successful) also php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php this with CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE should return `200`

Answer (score 2):

I used DOM for my code part. I called my desire page and filtered data using `getElementsByTagName('td')`
Here i want the status of my relays from the device page. every time i want updated status of relays. for that i used below code.

```
$keywords = array();
$domain = array('http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@URL/index.htm');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
foreach ($domain as $key => $value) {
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($value);
    //$anchor_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
    //$anchor_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $anchor_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($anchor_tags as $tag) {
        $keywords[] = strtolower($tag->nodeValue);
        //echo $keywords[0];
    }
}
```

Then i get my desired relay name and status in `$keywords[]` array.
Here i am sharing [image: screenshot] of Output.

If you want to read all messages in the main page. then first you have to collect all link for separate messages. Then you can use it for further same process.